# Java Apache FTPClient stalls when requesting a second file after a bad first file request

Tags: java, ftp-client

I'm trying to use FTPClient in Java and I got it to work fine when retrieving a single, correct file. It takes about 1 second and then continues correctly. Now I'm trying to make it recover if it gets a bad remote path.

So... retrieveFile(badPath) -> Takes about 1 minute to tell me: 550 File not found or permission problem.

I send another retrieveFile(goodPath) -> Command goes out, 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection. And just stays there! Any ideas?

Note that two correct requests work fine as well. Is there some kind of special recovery that needs to be done from a 550?

```
public class FTPFetch
{

// Creating FTP Client instance
FTPClient ftp = null;

// Constructor to connect to the FTP Server
public FTPFetch(String host, int port, String username, String password) throws Exception
{

    ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    int reply;
    ftp.connect(host, port);
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
    {
        ftp.disconnect();
        throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
    }
    ftp.login(username, password);
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
}

// Download the FTP File from the FTP Server
public boolean downloadFTPFile(String source, String destination)
{
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination))
    {
        if (this.ftp.retrieveFile(source, fos))
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
// Disconnect the connection to FTP
public void disconnect()
{
    if (this.ftp.isConnected())
    {
        try
        {
            this.ftp.logout();
            this.ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException f)
        {
            // do nothing as file is already saved to server
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
if (!ftpobj.downloadFTPFile(s, temp[temp.length - 1]))
                {
                    if (s.contains("bd0"))
                    {
                        File f2 = new File(temp[temp.length - 1]);
                        errorLog.warn("/bd0 path not found on remote CCU. Attempting /bd5.");
                        ftpobj.downloadFTPFile(s.replace("bd0", "bd5"), temp[temp.length - 1]);
                    } else
                    {
                        File f2 = new File(temp[temp.length - 1]);
                        errorLog.warn("/bd5 path not found on remote CCU. Attempting /bd0.");
                        ftpobj.downloadFTPFile(s.replace("bd5", "bd0"), temp[temp.length - 1]);
                    }
                }
```

My output:

```
230 User logged in
TYPE I
200 Type set to I, binary mode
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,20,40,21,19,117)
RETR /bd5/CU_Anthony/PN1008TestDir.zip
550 File "/bd5/CU_Anthony/PN1008TestDir.zip" not found or permission problem
[WARN ] 03-14-2017 12:48:26 [main] DataAdapterFB1 - /bd5 path not found on      remote CCU. Attempting /bd0.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,20,40,21,19,117)
RETR /bd0/CU_Anthony/PN1008TestDir.zip
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection
```

On the server side, I see after the 2nd request a Data Connection Error occurs but I have no indication as to why:

```
0x1890f20 (tFtpdServ0): (3170) data xfer failed: read 4096 bytes, wrote -1 bytes
0x1890f20 (tFtpdServ0): ftpdCmdSend: <426 Data connection error>
0x1890f20 (tFtpdServ0): (4136) sent 426 Data connection error

0x1890f20 (tFtpdServ0): (3413) Closing sock 55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure why it worked but putting it into Local Active Mode instead of Local Passive mode, it worked.